# 10 months per page by Wordpress kriesi pagination

Tags: wordpress

I use Wordpress kriesi pagination to add pagination into the website.
http://www.kriesi.at/archives/how-to-build-a-wordpress-post-pagination-without-plugin

The post are listed.
January 2014
Post name
Post name
December 2013
Post name
November 2013
Post name
Post name
Post name
Post name

I need to have 10 months per page.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
function kriesi_pagination($pages = '', $range = 5)
```

Comment: And how it helps me to have 10 months per page? Each month can have any limit.